# DHTMLX Gantt Chart is not storing to Database

Tags: java, php, mysql, charts, dhtml

I'm currently doing a Scheduling module for our project, and to be able to achieve this, we are going to use DHTMLX Gantt. However, I cannot store the values that is entered into the gantt chart!

Here is my code for the chart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css" rel="stylesheet">     
   <script src="http://export.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api.js"></script>  
   <script src="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input value="Export to PDF" type="button" onclick='gantt.exportToPDF()'>


    <div id="gantt_here" style='width:1000px; height:400px;'></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        gantt.init("gantt_here");
        gantt.load("events.php");

        var dp = new dataProcessor("events.php");
        dp.init(gantt);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code for the events.php

```
include ('codebase/connector/db_sqlite3.php');
include ('codebase/connector/gantt_connector.php');

 $dbtype = "MySQL";
 $res=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db("myfirstdb");

$gantt = new JSONGanttConnector($res, $dbtype);

$gantt->mix("open", 1);

$gantt->render_links("gantt_links", "id", "source,target,type");
$gantt->render_table("gantt_tasks","id",
    "start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent");

?>
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You php code seems ok. What happens when you try saving the event, can you check the server response? It may contain an error message.
Try also enabling logging for gantt connector so you could see an actual sql requests and their results
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__errors.html

One other thing - make sure you've enabled auto increment for id column, otherwise connector will be unable to insert new records